# Display Screen colors on laptop vs desktop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, hardware, calibration

I do my work on a laptop.

I have this problem and I'm trying to find a solution which the problem is when I set screen brightness on 100%, the colors on my screen are mixing up with the backlight of the screen, and I dont get the true colors of the picture's.

When I send the pictures to other people they see a different colors like more saturation or more or less of the adjustments.

Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The baisc idea is that you need to calibrate your monitor with hardware like this: http://www.colormunki.com/

So then you will know that other peoples monitor are simply wrong... and they need to be calibrated too.

Calibration also is afected by the working environment.

Aditionally you could use, like go-junta say, a real monitor... and calibrate it too.

Comment: Well since the backlights are mixing up with colors on the monitor its not of the bestest screens so i have to buy a new monitor. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 6):

Laptop displays have come a long way but the main factor in the problem you describe is the location where the laptop is used. A desktop monitor is more or less glued to a fixed location and once calibrated and profiled, it will display consistent color. The critical factor here is the absolute need to calibrate and profile the laptop. While doing that, consider the ambient light levels where it may be used and set the screen luminance to appropriate level(s). I use an i1 Display Pro and set my desktop to 100 candellas per square meter which sets the monitor to a level that suits my environment. If I had a brighter environment I would set it to 120 or maybe higher.

When it comes to laptop screen calibration, this value needs to be selectable depending on the need. You may consider creating three or four calibrations written to different profile files for low, medium, and bright environments with the candella per square meter value ranging from say 80, 100, 120, 150 and include this value in the profile file name. When you are at Starbucks with three sides covered with windows, you may choose the profile for 150 c/square m, in the back room of Panera's you may switch to 80. This you need to do before starting your application like Lightroom or Photoshop at the system level. This will likely give you a better control of what the screen shows and how your visual system responds to it.

You may want to take a look at a related article I wrote on my site:

http://www.keptlight.com/your-photo-editing-workspace/

Comment: Since you mentioned location, now i realise that i work in a room where there's a window behind me, maybe thats good because i can set my laptop brightness to 100% and it wont be hard for me to work on 100% and ill have better colors on my screen otherwise if it was dark room im not able to work on 100% brightness. Thank you for your help and ill check the link which i know it will helpful for me

Comment: @IvanStavreski, it is not a good idea to have a window behind you or one on the side casting light in the screen. The laptop brightness at 100% is also not a good idea, it should be set by the calibration device, calibration settings, and the candellas per square meter. If you do not calibrate and profile your displays, I cannot over emphasize the importance of it, it is a MUST. Take a look at my article at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, laptop monitors are probably the least reliable for color accuracy. Not only is the quality itself usually inferior to a good old monitor, but also other energy saving settings can affect the way the color is rendered.

**To my knowledge, most designers simply connect a "real" monitor to their laptop computer.**

So the best solution is probably to purchase a display, calibrate it, and use the right color profile and color spaces for your pictures and the projects you're working on!

I'm not saying there's no other solutions, but that's probably the simplest way to fix your issue and you'll gain extra comfort too. You should still be able to get some "okay" results with the laptop only by making sure you're using the right color space, gamma, calibration and profiles but there's *still* so many things that can affect the color that it ends up not being a very good tool for serious work. At some point it requires you to interpret how color will look like to others and that requires expert level experience (and demands lot of energy too) in color management!

Comment: i thought about buying new screen which is the best solution but before that i wanted to know if i can do something to fix this so that i dont have to spend money on screen. Thank you for your help !